# Using XSD.exe for c# code gen, ignores empty nodes in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, musicxml

Maybe I'm not doing this correctly. But I'm using [MusicXML](http://www.musicxml.com), along with XSD.exe to generate the C# classes against the DTD.

According to the [documentation](http://www.musicxml.com/tutorial/the-midi-compatible-part/chords/), along with a [sample xml file](http://downloads2.makemusic.com/musicxml/BeetAnGeSample.xml), the `<NOTE>` element contains an empty `<CHORD>` element, if the `<NOTE>` is a part of a `<CHORD>`. The code generated looks like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("chord", typeof(empty))]
```

When I deserialize the XML into a c# object, it works great, but the `<CHORD>` seems to disappear. Does .NET just ignore the `CHORD` element in this sample XML?

```
  <note>
    <chord/>
    <pitch>
      <step>E</step>
      <alter>-1</alter>
      <octave>4</octave>
    </pitch>
    <duration>1</duration>
  </note>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean "`<chord>` seems to disappear" when deserializing?

Comment: The note c# object does not having anything related to a chord, it does not make it through the deserialization.

Comment: Are you meaning that when it's *serialized* the output doesn't have the empty chord node?  Deserialization is taking the input and creating an object.  Serialization is the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean the chord element dissapears when you serialize to XML, as null elements don't serialize by default

If you want to render it as an empty element like

```
<chord />
```

you can set use the isnullable property
[XML Serialization and null value - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711723/xml-serialization-and-null-value-c-sharp)

As linked in another question you might want to have a look at this article about the representation of null in XML Schema files:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-null/index.html

Comment: I mean that when I load the XML into a custom object, the chord property disappears from the object.

Comment: I think I've got it figured out, thank you for your answer, I've read that all now. Not sure what fixed it.

Comment: The property will be null if the element is missing, going from XML to a C# object is deserializing, going from C# object to XML is serializing, so you are deserializing, and if the element is missing or empty it won't serialize it. Post your serialization class definition if you have any more questions on how to serialize elements correctly