# Is there a straight forward way to [De]serialize a bool field as an element being present/not present

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

Assume I have a class like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
<Person>
<Name>Thomas</Name>
<Age>33</Age>
<Deleted />
</Person>
```

or

```
<Person>
<Name>Thomas</Name>
<Age>33</Age>
</Person>
```

Depending on the setting of .Deleted = true|false.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int) answer...

Basically, you want to use the XmlSerializer ShouldSerialize.  Note that in this case, you'll probably end up with a true tag, instead of just the presence of the tag; you might have to do some more workaround if that's not good.