# Serializing Objects with the DataContract/Data member for WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I am attempting to Serialize my data layer objects. these are complex objects that have properties, methods and collections of objects.

All the classes are inheriting from a base class  Which gets serialized.

```
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Person))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Client))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Professional))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ProfessionalApptHistory))]
    [KnownType(typeof(DailySchedule))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Option))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PersonType))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ProfessionClientInteractionType))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ProfessionalClientInteractions))]
    [KnownType(typeof(ProfessionalCalendar))]
    public abstract class CMBase
    {
        protected designs3_OurTimeEntities _entities = new designs3_OurTimeEntities();
        [DataMember()]
        public abstract bool IsPersisted { get; internal set; }
    }
```

I have a person class which also get serialized

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Person")]
    [KnownType(typeof(Professional))]
    [KnownType(typeof(Client))]
    public abstract class Person : CMBase
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public int PersonId { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public int PersonTypeId { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string ImageLocation { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public Bitmap Image { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public Guid MembershipUserId { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime? ActivationStartDate { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Email { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public bool ShowDefaultPage { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public bool IsClient { get; internal set; }

        [DataMember()]        
        public override bool IsPersisted
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.PersonId == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            internal set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

...
        }

then I have this class which doenst get serialized

```
    [DataContract(Name = "Professional")]
    public class Professional : Person
    {
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime DateStartedInProfession { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public int? ShopId { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime LastPayment { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime NextPaymentDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public DateTime TerminationDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public int? Rating { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public bool hasSystemAccess { get; internal set; }
        [DataMember()]
        public List<SaveResult> SaveResults { get; internal set; }
...
}
```

I also have other classes that don't get serialized and I don't understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Serialize a nullable int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int)

It has some approaches you could follow.

Answer (score 1):

For late visitors (just like me):
**Inheritance** is the problem, as it is discussed here: 
[Definiting the Serialization DataMember in Interface and then using it in a class implementing said interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768451/definiting-the-serialization-datamember-in-interface-and-then-using-it-in-a-clas)

If `Person` would be an interface and `Profession` would implement that interface, that would work. This is because the attribute `DataMember` cannot be inherited.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
[DataMember()]
public int? ShopId { get; set; }
```

To

```
[DataMember()]
public Nullable<int> ShopId { get; set; }
```

I'm sure that Nullable get's serialized, I'm not 100% sure that's your only problem though.

Comment: I changed the nullable types so they are not nullable anymore, so they read like this [DataMember()] public int ShopId { get; set; }. It still is not serializing when I update the service reference. Is there a problem with the base class inheritance?

Comment: `int?` is syntactic sugar for Nullable<int> handled by the compiler. There should be no visible difference to the serializer.