# Deserialize XML in C# - Return null on wrong format

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have thw following XML Code that I want to deserialize:

```
<a>
   <b> n/a </b>
</a>
```

Now b is normally an integer, but sometimes "n/a" for not available. Whenever I deserialize the above XML, I get an Exception that I use a wrong format... what is correct.
But I need the int simply to be a null value

```
public class a
{
    Nullable<int> b;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could do that would be to use something like:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int? B {get;set;}

public bool ShouldSerializeBSerialized() {
    return B.HasValue;
}
[XmlElement("b")]
public string BSerialized {
    get { return B.ToString(); }
    set {
       int tmp;
       if(value != null && int.TryParse(value.Trim(), out tmp))
       {
           B = tmp;
       }
    }
}
```

Here:

- `B` is the `int?` we'll use to store the data
- `BSerialized` is a shim property that handles the parsing etc
- `ShouldSerializeBSerialized` ensures we only serialize valid data

Comment: +1 and deleted my answer which said to do something like this; only I didn't bother with code.

Comment: This is how I finaly realized it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the below:

[Serialize a nullable int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int)

Comment: There's a difference between a nullable int and an element with non-integer content. This will not work here (see the `N/A`)

Comment: you are right :-). I think the only way is to write some code to try to parse the int