# How to deserialize Nullable<bool>?

Tags: c#, xml, nullable, xml-deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a `Nullable<bool>` from my XML file. My expectation was that a XMLAttribute which was not found in my XMLElement is `null` and if it's found it will be `true`or `false`. Same for serialization. My variable will be written if it's not null.

Anyways, everytime I'm trying to deserialize my XML an `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown.

My class looks like this

```
[XMLArray("Users")]
public class User
{
    [XMLAttribute("copy")]
    public bool? copy;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at this approach, the top answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri   It basically wraps a property around the nullable bool and serialize/deserializes that one.  Ignore the bool property from serialization.

Comment: You could use 
`public bool ShouldSerializecopy() {return copy.HasValue;}` as shown here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[XMLArray("Users")]
public class User
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool? m_copy;

    [XmlAttribute("copy")]
    public string copy
    {
        get { return (m_copy.HasValue) ? m_copy.ToString() : null; }
        set { m_copy = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? bool.Parse(value) : default(bool?); }
    }
}
```

I got the solution from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295697/deserializing-empty-xml-attribute-value-into-nullable-int-property-using-xmlseri) to a post linked by sylon. Thanks alot!