# How to ignore a nullable property from serialization if it is null or empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization

I have a class which is used for Xml Serialization.

Inside which I have a nullable property which is decorated with XmlAttribute:

```
 [XmlAttribute("lastUpdated")]
 public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

How to ignore the property from serialization if it is null or empty?

I've tried the below but it doesn't serialize when there is a value (always ignores):

```
  [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime? LastUpdatedValue { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("lastUpdated")]
       public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeLastUpdated()
        {
            return LastUpdatedValue.HasValue;
        }
```

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int?rq=1

Comment: What do you expect the XML to look like? In this case you'll get `<lastUpdated xsi:nil="true"/>` if the property is null; you could either post-process your xml (easier) or you can write a XmlWriter class (harder, performs better). There are other options that are both hard and bloat your code.

Comment: no I just want to ignore the xmlattribute if it's null. but DateTime? is not serializable. How to replace it?

Answer (score 12):

Nullable is not directly supported by XmlSerialization.

If you want use a nullable property you must use a non nullable property and add a boolean property with the same name of property with the suffix "Specified" which specifie when the property must be serializable.

An example with your case :

```
    private DateTime? _lastUpdated;

    [XmlAttribute("lastUpdated")]
    public DateTime LastUpdated {
        get {
            return (DateTime)_lastUpdated;
        }
        set
        {
            _lastUpdated = value;
        }
    }

    public bool LastUpdatedSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastUpdated.HasValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is I can't serialize it anymore using XmlSerializer. I'm getting this error: +  InnerException {"There was an error reflecting property 'LastUpdated'."} System.Exception {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Sorry, I was too fast, I correct and edit my code. Can you try this ?

Comment: @TheLight can you accept my answer like best response ?

Comment: `return (DateTime)_lastUpdated;` will throw `InvalidOperationException` if `_lastUpdated` doesn't has a value.

Comment: Where is LastUpdatedSpecified used ?

Answer (score 6):

I know this topic is old.  This is the solution I came with.   A class which encapsulates the type, and has implicit casting to the type.  When serializing, the member variable can be marked with **IsNullable = false** without getting compiler errors, and blocking it from being serialized when null.

```
public class Optional<T> where T : struct, IComparable
{
    public Optional(T valueObject)
    {
        Value = valueObject;
    }

    public Optional()
    {
    }

    [XmlText]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator T(Optional<T> objectToCast)
    {
        return objectToCast.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Optional<T>(T objectToCast)
    {
        return new Optional<T>(objectToCast);
    }
}
```

Then use it in your class

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "foo")]
public class foo
{
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "myInteger", isNullable = false)]
   Optional<int> myInt;
}
```

You can do things like

```
        myFoo.myInt = 7;
        int j = 8 + myFoo.myInt;
```

For all purposes it's an int.  For serialization purposes, it can be null and blocked from being serialized.

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine for me!

When using it with another custom datatype (my bools need to be serialized as Y/N), I've changed the IComparable to IComparable<T>, where I could implement IComparable<CustomBool> in my CustomBool type

Comment: This doesn't work for [XmlElement(DataType="date")]. 'date' is an invalid value for the XmlElementAttribute.DataType property. The property may only be specified for primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

This is working for me.

```
    [XmlIgnore]
    public float? Speed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("Speed")]
    public float SpeedSerializable
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Speed.Value;
        }
        set { this.Speed = value; }
    }

    public bool ShouldSerializeSpeedSerializable()
    {
          return Speed.HasValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: This works for sure in SOAP contracts in WCF. I haven't tested in other Xml serialization scenarios.

When using a `[DataContract]` you can use

`[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]`

- For a `boolean` it will only emit the value if it is `true`.
- For a `nullable boolean` it will only emit if it is not `null`.
- For a `string` it will only emit the value if it isn't `null`.
- For an `int` it will only emit the value if it isn't `0`.

etc.

Make sure to put `[DataContract]` on the class itself and `[DataMember]` on all members you want serialized, whether you're specifying `EmitDefaultValue` or not.

> Setting the EmitDefaultValue property to false is not a recommended
>   practice. It should only be done if there is a specific need to do so
>   (such as for interoperability or to reduce data size).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.emitdefaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx)**:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public DateTime? LastUpdated  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It could not be used with attributes. It is only used fo elements.

Comment: This does the opposite of what was asked. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable):

"Gets or sets a value that indicates whether the XmlSerializer must serialize a member that is set to null as an empty tag with the xsi:nil attribute set to true."