# How I can Ignore Null properties to be serialized using SharpSerializer

Tags: c#, deserialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, sharpserializer

I am using SharpSerializer to serialize my objects to XML. By default all public properties are serialized.

Is it possible to exclude null-values from serialization?

For example:

```
public class Test
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
}

private void Main(string[] args)
{
   Test t = new Test();
   t.Id = 1; //Serialize this
   t.Text = null; //Don't serialize this

   //Do Serialization
}
```

Comment: look here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244953/serialize-a-nullable-int

Comment: @Maksim Simkin : I am looking for solution that works with SharpSerializer.